# How can I change color of toolbar in ionic according to user input

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic app and I want the user to be able to choose the theme

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h21LD.png]

How can I effectively change all the toolbar backgrounds in the app ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to learn some details about the expected format of questions on the site

Answer (score 1):

Use the power of cascading stylesheets. Define a theme class at the toplevel like the material Design topclass `md` in ionic and Build your Themes like

```
.theme1 ion-header toolbar{
  [...]
}
```

Then alter this topclass on User Choice with `ngClass`

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways:

1. You can use a variable and assign that variable to `color` in your html file.
2. You can create a css class for each theme and depending on the value of a variable that changes with user selection assign that class to your components.

If all you need to do is changing the color of header, use method 1. Change the value of `color` variable dynamically:

```
<ion-header>
   <ion-navbar color={{color}}>
   <ion-title >Home</ion-title>
</ion-navbar>
```

you can see the complete code here and working example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-6j7dz7